# Unable to obtain: Columns missing in one input file but present in other files should return NA in output file

Tags: r, data.table, tidyr, rbind

I have various txt files, where each file contains multiple columns but not all columns are present in all the files.
For example,

Columns of Txt File1

```
D/T  City_Name  Temp  Pres  Wind_Hor  Wind_Ver  S_Moist  Temp1  Pres1  Wind1  S_Moist1
20200101  Mi  27  1019  287  278  78  1  2  2  1
20200101  Mi  28  1019  289  277  78  2  2  1  3
```

Columns of Txt File2

```
D/T  City_Name  Temp  Wind_Hor  Rainf  S_Moist   Temp1  Wind1  S_Moist1
20200501  Ch  29  88  74  78  2  2  2  3
20200501  Ch  26  83  74  76  2  3  3  3
```

Columns of Txt File3

```
D/T  City_Name  Pres  Wind_Vert  Rainf  S_Moist  Pres1  Wind1  Rainf1  S_Moist1    
20180701  Ny  1017  247  78  78  4  2  2  2
20180702  Ny  1017  249  79  79  2  3  3  3
```

I ran a code in R to process these files and obtain 1 output csv for each txt file.

My desired output is to have all the 7 columns in all the output files and if a particular column is absent in the input, then it should have NA values in the output.

Desired output columns of Txt File1

```
D_T  City_Name  Temp  Pres  Wind_Hor  Wind_Ver  Rainf  S_Moist
202001  Mi  26  1018  288  277  NA  77
202002  Mi  27  1018  288  278  NA  77
```

Desired output Columns of Txt File2

```
D_T  City_Name  Temp  Pres  Wind_Hor  Wind_Ver  Rainf  S_Moist
202005  Ch  28  NA  287  NA  77  77
202006  Ch  27  NA  284  NA  79  78
```

Desired output Columns of Txt File3

```
D_T  City_Name  Temp  Pres  Wind_Hor  Wind_Vert  Rainf  S_Moist   
201807  Mi  NA  1016  NA  276  77  79
201808  Mi  NA  1016  NA  276  77  81
```

My code is as follows:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

setwd("D:/Test3")

dirlist <- list.files(full.names = FALSE, no.. = TRUE) 

#Read the files
read_the_files <- function(filelist){
  lapply(filelist, function(file) {
    fread(file, skip = "D/T\tXY [XY]")             
  })
}

#Adjusting with Columns
adj_col_names <- function(dt_list){
  lapply(dt_list, FUN = function(x){
    #replace [] with () as use of [] may lead to issues
    colnames(x) <- gsub("\\[", "(", colnames(x))
    colnames(x) <- gsub("\\]", ")", colnames(x))

    #Applying quality codes given in the data and range given in paper
    if ("Temp1" %in% colnames(x)) {
      x[Temp1 != 5, Temp := NA]
      x[Temp < 0 | Temp > 40, Temp := NA]
    }

    if ("Pres1" %in% colnames(x)) {
      x[Pres1 != 5, Pres := NA]
      x[Pres < 1000 | Pres > 1300, Pres := NA]
    }

for (idx in seq_along(dirlist)){
  filelist <- list.files(path = dirlist[idx], full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, pattern = 
                       ".txt$")
  dt_ <- read_the_files(filelist)
  dt.tidied <- adj_col_names(dt_)

  #bind, filling missing columns to NA  
  merged <- rbindlist(dt.tidied, fill = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)

  #Choosing the columns in the output    
  sel_col <- c('D/T', 'City_Name', 'Temp', 'Pres', 'Wind_Hor', 'Wind_Ver', 'Rainf', 'S_Moist')

  #calculating monthly average
  avg_mn <- merged %>%      
    select(any_of(sel_col)) %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    group_by(D_T = lubridate::floor_date(`D/T`, "1 month")) %>%         
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~ if(mean(is.na(.x)) > 0.1) NA else mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))     #summarise only numeric columns
    write.csv(paste0(dirlist[idx],"_mn.csv"))
```

I cannot change my code due to various dependencies. I can only modify. Could anyone please help me in modifying it to obtain the desired output?

Tested code as per jkatam's answer:

```
dfs1 <- list.files(path = 'D:/Test3', pattern = "*txt", recursive = TRUE)
var <- c('D/T', 'City_Name', 'Temp', 'Pres', 'Wind_Hor', 'Wind_Ver', 'Rainf', 'S_Moist')
lapply(dfs1, \(x) {
  dfn <- get(x, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  dfn[[var[which(is.na(match(var,names(dfn))))]]] <- NA
  dfn <- dfn %>% select(all_of(var))
  return(assign(x,dfn,envir = .GlobalEnv))
})
```

I am getting the error:

```
Error in get(x, envir = .GlobalEnv) :
object 'Mi/Mi_2020-01_0100.txt' not found
```

Comment: could you first read all the datasets into a list. ie: `rbindlist(lapply(your_file_list, read.table))`

Comment: I am not able to read the datasets using the above command. Due to varying structure of files (different no.of initial rows to skip), I have created a function to read the files. Environment shows dt_ and dt_tidied as large list but using them in above command returns an error: 'Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection'

Comment: If you have read the files and they are in a list (all the files) then directly use `rbindlist` No need of for-loop again. or simply `dplyr::bind_rows(your_list)`

Comment: to `rbindlist` you will need to add `fill=TRUE` and (if the column order is not the same) `use.names=TRUE`.

Comment: @r2evans that's already there in my code but it is not giving me the desired output.

Comment: @Onyambu Could you please tell me how and where in my code I can use dplyr::bind_rows(your_list)

Comment: You said you had read your data into a list. use `bind_rows` on your list

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code where I assumed that you have different dataframes like `df1` and `df2` etc., which you would like to check if expected columns exists or not and if not exists then derive that column with NA and output the dataframes which you can later export to csv

```r
dfs1 <- c('df1','df2')

var <- c('City_Name',  'Temp',  'Pres' , 'Wind_Hor' , 'Wind_Ver' , 'Rainf' , 'S_Moist')

lapply(dfs1, \(x) {
  dfn <- get(x, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  dfn[[var[which(is.na(match(var,names(dfn))))]]] <- NA
  dfn <- dfn %>% select(all_of(var))
  return(assign(x,dfn,envir = .GlobalEnv))
})
```

Comment: Thanks but I do not have dataframes. Instead, I have files. Could you please tell me how to perform the procedure that you mentioned with files instead of dataframes.

Comment: I tried your code with a list of files (mentioned in the post) but it is giving me an error. Also, I tried to place it just above adj_col_names but I am not sure if it is the correct location for these lines of code. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Using your input files, I did a few things:

- named them `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, and `file3.txt`
- changed all spaces to single tabs and ensured no trailing tabs on a line (file3)
- added `S_Rain1` to file2, since it has 9 column names and 10 data columns

Then I ran this code:

```r
files <- list.files(pattern = "txt$", full.names = TRUE)
alldat <- lapply(setNames(nm = files), fread)
rbindlist(alldat, idcol = "path", fill = TRUE, use.names = TRUE) %>%
  setnames("D/T", "D_T") %>%
  .[, fwrite(.SD, sub("txt$", "tab", path[1]), sep = "\t", na = "NA"),
    .SDcols = c("D_T", "City_Name", "Temp", "Pres", "Wind_Hor", "Wind_Ver", "Rainf", "S_Moist"),
    by = .(path)]
```

The resulting files:

- `file1.csv`:

  ```r
  "D_T"   "City_Name" "Temp"  "Pres"  "Wind_Hor"  "Wind_Ver"  "Rainf" "S_Moist"
  20200101    "Mi"    27  1019    287 278 NA  78
  20200101    "Mi"    28  1019    289 277 NA  78
  ```
- `file2.csv`

  ```
  "D_T"   "City_Name" "Temp"  "Pres"  "Wind_Hor"  "Wind_Ver"  "Rainf" "S_Moist"
  20200501    "Ch"    29  NA  88  NA  74  78
  20200501    "Ch"    26  NA  83  NA  74  76
  ```
- `file3.csv`

  ```
  "D_T"   "City_Name" "Temp"  "Pres"  "Wind_Hor"  "Wind_Ver"  "Rainf" "S_Moist"
  20180701    "Ny"    NA  1017    NA  NA  78  78
  20180702    "Ny"    NA  1017    NA  NA  79  79
  ```

The quotes were added because we provided `na=""` which adds the literal text `NA`. The quotes can be suppressed by adding `quote=FALSE` to the `fwrite(..)` expression.

Note: the contents above render with spaces due to StackOverflow code rendering; they are indeed tabs in the resulting files.

Comment: I tried the code by modifying it as per my code.  Did I modify it correctly? because it is giving me this error: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  input= must be a single character string containing a file name, a system command containing at least one space, a URL starting 'http[s]://', 'ftp[s]://' or 'file://', or, the input data itself containing at least one \n or \r   Also, could you please add comments in your code

Comment: Does `files` look reasonable for you? Do all of the files exist and are they all formatted properly? Are there extra filenames in `files` that should not be read into the batch?

Comment: files look reasonable to me, the only difference being that because I am processing the multiple files iteratively, I have used a loop at this step (pls refer to 'filelist' in my code). Yes all files exist. Though files are not formatted properly, it has been taken care of in my code.  As file names are quite large, I have kept folder's name as the file name. It would be helpful if you could please merge your code with mine and provide it with comments for easier understanding